# Clear InputFields after clicked submit using Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I wonder if any one knows how to clear all the input fields after push the save button "Submitted"??
When i return to the page my values are still there.

This is my code that i am using.

```
@page "/testform"
@inject BlazorApp6.Data.Person person
@inject BlazorApp6.DBContext.ValidationTestContext Context
@inject BlazorApp6.Interface.INterface Manager

<EditForm Model="@person" OnValidSubmit="@CreatePerson">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value=Person.Name class="form-control" id="Name" />
            <ValidationMessage For=@(() => Person.Name) />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Age">Age</label>
            <InputNumber @bind-Value=Person.Age class="form-control" id="Age" />
            <ValidationMessage For=@(() => Person.Age) />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
    </EditForm>

@code {



    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        person.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    private void CreatePerson()
    {

        Manager.Create(person);
        
       
    }

}
```

Comment: Your not using EditForms OnSubmit or OnValidSubmit. https://blazor-university.com/forms/handling-form-submission/

Comment: @Orak, I have added that now. But it does not still work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reset all values. Easiest way:

```
private void CreatePerson()
{
    Manager.Create(person);
    person = new Person();            
}
```

and you shouldn't need StateHasChanged:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // person.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
}
```

otherwise you have to `-=` and `+=` the event(s) around `new Person()`

Comment: I see you inject Person, That is not a good approach. Inject services, not entities.

Comment: I get this when i try that 
"The type or namespace name 'Person' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
Can this message have some thing with the @injection to do?

Comment: Yes, `@include BlazorApp6.Data`

Answer (score -1):

Write a function to clear the input fields

```
private void ClearInputFields()
{
    person.Name = string.Empty;  

}
```

Then call the method after a successfull submission