# After adding record to my database form is still filled with added info

Tags: c#, blazor

i am working with Blazor-Server and here is a thing.

After adding record to database my form is still filled with old data. How i should re-render or re-load it?

This is my form:

```
        <EditForm Model="@Post" OnValidSubmit="@AddPost" OnInvalidSubmit="@Invalid">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
            @if(Success == true)
            {
                <div class="alert @Status">
            <p>Your entry must be reviewed by administrator.</p>
                </div>
            }

            <p><InputText name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Post title" @bind-Value="@Post.Title"></InputText></p>
            <p><InputTextArea name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Post description" @bind-Value="@Post.Description"></InputTextArea></p>
            <p><InputText name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick" @bind-Value="@Post.Author"></InputText></p>
            <p>
                <InputSelect id="category" class="form-select" @bind-Value="@Post.Category">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">Categories list</option>
                    @foreach (var category in Categories!)
                    {
                        <option value="@category.Category">@category.Category</option>
                        
                    }
                </InputSelect>
            </p>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>Post.Title)" />

        <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button></p>
        </EditForm>`
```

I have been trying to re-render with OnAfterRenderAsync, but cannot get it :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459033/clear-inputfields-after-clicked-submit-using-blazor

Comment: no, but i fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear InputFields after clicked submit using Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459033/clear-inputfields-after-clicked-submit-using-blazor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I have to create new model.

like this:

```
Post = new();
StateHasChanged();
```